# how can i change the start id number in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to change the initial number of id from 1 to 2000.
My table :

```
id  value     type 
1   e         photo     
2   f         text
3   g         photo
```

and here is what i want as result:

```
id      value     type 
2001    e         photo     
2002    f         text
2003    g         photo
```

Comment: `UPDATE mytable SET id = id + 2000 ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: Do you already have entries in the table and want to change them? Or do you want to define the first id for an empty table?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I already have entries in table paul,by the way your solution works perfectly,thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the query to change the auto increment value in your table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT=2000;
```

If you just want to add 2000 to all the IDs you can do:

```
UPDATE my_table SET id = id + 2000;
```

But its not very clean to do that.

Comment: For what reason do the ids need changed?